# how to trace or debug javascript closures in firebug

Tags: javascript, closures

How do i trace the values of local variables in closure, and also the execution flow of closures in firebug. or is there any other tools that is specifically for debugging closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can debug the javascript closure with Firebug.  On Script tab, you can see all the object instances as well as the state of the whole object. Please, Find it below the screenshot of firebug showing local variables in closure.

[image]
<sub>(source: [pengbos.com](http://pengbos.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/firebug.jpg))</sub>

If you want to learn more read this [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170823011455/http://getfirebug.com/logging)  and practice it.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome's [Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html) you can inspect the closure stack by setting a breakpoint (in the *Scope Variables* section):

[image: Closure stack inspection in Chrome Developer Tools]

I would assume Firebug has similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [Closure Inspector](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Closure_Inspector) of Firebug.