# How to debug JavaScript closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

1. The question is why debug into a function, how we know that the closure content which the function refer to?

   I'm aware that Google chrome will display a closure in "Scope Variables" section, but what about other browsers? (updated: FF has similar thing but doesn't call it "closure" but just like local variables)
2. Motivation of the first question is actually coming along while reading the <Learning jQuery,3rd edition> - Appendix A.

   At page 355, author saying following code fragment will cause memory leak at IE because of loop reference(click handler refer to a closure content which has the DOM button).

   I'm just curious about whether it is the case by debug into the click handler to the closure content.However Google chrome doesn't show any closure variable.

   Thus I'm wondering how author know the loop reference issue..

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var button = document.getElementById('button-1');
  button.onclick = function() {
    $.print('hello');
    return false;
  };
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: The author knows because (in this case) it's obvious: the variable "button" refers to a DOM node, and its "onclick" property is set to a function, and that function has the variable in its scope.

Comment: Wait, isn't this a problem only if the handler actually references button?  Is this the right example?

Comment: @Pointy My curision is actually here that the `onclick` handler function does not have any reference to variable `button`. Therefore, how variable `button` could be closure of that function? Otherwise am I thinking in a very incorrect way?

Comment: If you put a break at line `$.print`, you are NOT able to any closure variable there. (In Google Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

I would refer you to use Firebug to debug your code. Its the best plugin available with  dont have the exact answer to the question but you may like to have a look at these links.

[Tools for debugging memory leaks in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573252/tools-for-debugging-memory-leaks-in-javascript)

[how to trace or debug javascript closures in firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921291/how-to-trace-or-debug-javascript-closures-in-firebug)

[Debugging closures in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379612/debugging-closures-in-javascript)

You can even check out the [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxW1dCjOstE&lr=1&uid=_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw) Link so as to get more information.

Hope I have tried Answering something useful.

Comment: The question is very specific. This answer is too generic. Please add more details.

Comment: @RobW I have edited my answer with few links. Hope this satisfies you a bit. Though they are not the perfect answer I assume. :)

Comment: @RobW The first link provides me one of the best solution I ever knew. It dosent answer the question perfectly but would give a great insight  though.

Comment: @ShivKumarGanesh Thanks your links. However those posts are basically telling us that either FF or Chrome is able to debug closure which I'm already aware. And this is not the issue I asked.